# Using zsh when run task in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

What I want to achieve is using zsh in "output" pane whenever I run a Task in VSCode, but it keep using `/bin/sh` instead. 
The "Terminal" pane is using zsh correctly though.

Here's my configurations:

```
➜  ~ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
➜  ~ which zsh
/bin/zsh
```

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "echo Im $0",
  "suppressTaskName": true,
  "isShellCommand": {
    "executable": "/bin/zsh"
  },
  "showOutput": "always",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "Test",
      "args": ["test"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the output when I run the Task is:
`Im /bin/sh`

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to do this now is the following:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": []
    }
  },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh"
```

As the other answer presents the deprecated way to do it.

Note that you can customize this profile with arguments if need be :)

Answer (score 4):

You could change the settings from menu `File -> Preferences -> Settings`. Then put the options to use `zsh` shell.

```
... another lines
... another lines
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "zsh"
```

[image: Screenshot from my experience]